# Resolving a Lagrange differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have been trying to solve a differential equation but I'm shard stucked.

The equation is:
$y = x(y')^2 - \frac{1}{y'}$

As it has Lagrange form, I do $y' = p$.

$y = xp^2 - \frac{1}{p}$

Taking differentials

$dy = p^2dx + [2xp + \frac{1}{p^2}]dp$

As $y'=p \rightarrow dy=pdx$

Resuming:

$pdx = p^2dx + [2xp + \frac{1}{p^2}]dp$

$pdx - p^2dx = [2xp + \frac{1}{p^2}]dp$

$[p - p^2]dx = [2xp + \frac{1}{p^2}]dp$

Okay, so... any idea of how to resolve this equation? I dont know how to follow...

Answer (score 1):

$$(p - p^2)dx = (2xp + \frac{1}{p^2})dp\quad\text{is OK.}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dp}=-\frac{2x}{p-1}-\frac{1}{p^3(p-1)}$$
This is a first order linear PDE for the function $x(p)$. Solving leads to :
$$x=\frac{1}{p(p-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2p^2(p-1)^2}+\frac{c}{(p-1)^2}$$
and with $\quad y=xp^2-\frac{1}{p} =\frac{p}{(p-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2}+\frac{c\:p^2}{(p-1)^2}-\frac{1}{p}\quad$ the solution is on parametric form :

$$\begin{cases}
x=\frac{1}{p(p-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2p^2(p-1)^2}+\frac{c}{(p-1)^2}\\
y=-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{p}{(p-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2}+\frac{c\:p^2}{(p-1)^2}
\end{cases}$$